# CMake - set variable from the contents of file during build time

Tags: cmake

I want to generate random seed for a 3rd party script (gen_source.py in example below) which expects it as a command-line argument. So far I was able to generate seed only during configure stage. Is there a way to pass seed value during build stage from a file? Note that I can't change gen_source.py script. Also, I need to avoid re-generating seed every time, so I used CMake caching which works fine and allows re-generation of seed when I need it. But I think it would make my code cleaner if I was able to do this example during build time.

```
execute_process(COMMAND bash -c "hexdump -v -e '1/1 \"%02X\"' -n 16 /dev/urandom"
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE SEED)
execute_process(COMMAND bash -c "echo seed = ${SEED}")
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_header.h"
  COMMAND python3 "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen_source.py" ${SEED}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass seed value during build stage from a file?

So just use add_custom_command instead of execute process.

```
add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/seed.txt
   COMMAND bash -c "hexdump -v -e '1/1 \"%02X\"' -n 16 /dev/urandom > ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/seed.txt
)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_header.h"
  COMMAND bash -c "python3 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen_source.py "$(cat ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/seed.txt)""
)
```

Some quoting fixes would be nice, like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/seed.txt"
   COMMAND sh -c
      [=[ hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02X"' -n 16 /dev/urandom > "$1" ]=]
      --
      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/seed.txt"
    VERBATIM
)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_header.h"
  DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/seed.txt"
  COMMAND sh -c
      [=[ python3 "$1" "$(cat "$2")" ]=]
      --
      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen_source.py"
      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/seed.txt"
    VERBATIM
)
add_custom_target(test ALL DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_header.h")
```

Comment: Appreciate your help but I have some quoting issues with both samples. Tried to fix, but in the end parameter was empty.

Comment: Use `sh -xc` for debugging. I saw a missing `"`. Let me test it..

Comment: Both are missing VERBATIM. See add_custom_command documentation. I assumed you are aware.

Comment: Seems to be working, thanks! Will try to understand how VERBATIM works and all that formatting.